# Core Location - Retroactively pulling information in Swift

Tags: swift, core-location

I have a question regarding CoreLocation within Swift. I'm currently running an app that pulls a user's location every second with CoreLocation. This is great and all, but it takes a ton of memory and battery to run (especially since my users want to use the app throughout the day). I'm wondering if there's a way to pull the location data from the past (x) seconds to plot like a map of sorts and process the information retroactively.

For example: If it had been 3 seconds since last refresh... On Refresh button-

```
var lastLocations = [(<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/26/16, 3:11:20 PM Mountain Daylight Time),(<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/26/16, 3:11:20 PM Mountain Daylight Time),(<+37.33233141,-122.03121860> +/- 5.00m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 7/26/16, 3:11:20 PM Mountain Daylight Time)]
```

Does anybody know if it's possible to pull information retroactively from CoreLocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Location doesn't give you history. If you want to have historical information, you need to collect and maintain it yourself.

Your memory problems could be fixed by saving the data to a file (maybe Core Data, maybe something else) so that you don't have to keep it all in memory. The battery issue depends on what exactly your app is doing. Getting Core Location updates once per second for long periods is, honestly, a really good way to run down the battery fast. Getting accurate location information requires power, and the more often you get the location, the more power you use.

If you actually need updates that often, you're stuck with it. But you can get much lower power requirements at the expense of less-frequent location updates by using other means-- for example, the "significant" location update option in Core Location.